# unittesting sqlalchemy updates in flask app

Tags: python, session, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a Flask app, which performs operations on a mysql database.  It uses sqlalchemy, and creates a session per request.  In my testing framework, I set up a session, then insert appropriate data and ensure removal afterward.  However, in my test, when I attempt to make sure that something was deleted (via a DELETE request to my Flask app), the row in my session is unaffected by the external thread.  Do I need to close and reopen my session to ensure proper deletion, or can I refresh it somehow, or am I doing this all wrong somehow that I'm missing?

```
class Endpoint(flask_restful.Resource):
    # in the webapp thread
    def delete(self,id):
        db.session.query(db.Table).filter(id=id).delete()
        db.session.commit()

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    # in the testing thread
    def setUp(self):
        self.data = db.session.add(db.Table())
        db.session.commit()
    def tearDown(self):
        self.data.delete()
        db.session.commit()
    def test_delete(self):
        requests.delete(flask.url_for(Endpoint, id=self.data.id))
        assert db.session.query(db.Table).filter(id = self.data.id).count() == 0
```